# Server missing "ldap.so"

Tags: php, ldap

I want to connect to ldap in php. However I'm getting this error

> exception 'adLDAPException' with message 'No LDAP support for PHP.
>   See: http://www.php.net/ldap'

I need to reference "ldap.so" in php.ini file. But I'm not sure how to get the file. Installed openldap but still no luck. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Do I need to recompile php ldap? if yes, what packages I need to install

Comment: What OS are you using? - Ubuntu, Fedora, BSD...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Answer (score 5):

Run either of these as `root` to install the missing extension.

Apt:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-ldap
```

Yum-based systems:

```
yum install php-ldap
echo "extension=ldap.so" >> /etc/php.ini
service httpd restart
```

For you, specifically, try installing directly from RPM:

x86_64:

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/php-ldap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64.rpm
deb -i php-ldap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

i386:

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/php-ldap-5.3.3-22.el6.i686.rpm
deb -i php-ldap-5.3.3-22.el6.i686.rpm
```

Comment: No package php-ldap available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Still saying no package found to install

Comment: If your hosting company is like one of mine, they have custom repos for VMs - Try resetting them to what comes with a stock CentOS install. The package should be available, from everything that I can find.

Comment: Can you run `yum repolist` and put the response in a comment or your question?

Comment: base  CentOS-6 - Base
extras CentOS-6 - Extras 
updates  CentOS-6 - Updates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41664/discussion-between-matcarlson-and-downmasters-com)